# Why isn't the GitHub Pages repository I pushed up to GitHub live?

Tags: github, hosting, github-pages

This is the repository hosted on GitHub pages:
https://github.com/nezmustafa123/todolistjquery.github.io

Did I not name it properly?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The html file has to be named **index.html**, for Github pages to load it.

Answer (score 1):

It *is* live, it just isn't where you expect to find it: https://nezmustafa123.github.io/todolistjquery.github.io/

There are two types of GitHub Pages sites:

1. [User / organization sites](https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages/#user-and-organization-pages-sites)
2. [Project sites](https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages/#project-pages-sites)

### User / organization sites

Repositories for user / organization sites must be named `<your-username>.github.io` (in your case `nezmustafa123.github.io`) and are built from the `master` branch. They are hosted at `https://<your-username>.github.io/`.

If you want to host on `https://todolistjquery.github.io/` you need to own the `todolistjquery` user or organization.

### Project sites

What you have is a *project* site since the repository name doesn't match your GitHub username. Project sites are hosted at `https://<your-username>.github.io/<repository-name>/`. Here your repository name is `todolistjquery.github.io`, all of which is included in your GitHub Pages URL.

Project sites can be built from the `gh-pages` branch, from the `master` branch, or from the `docs/` folder in the `master` branch. This is configurable.

I suggest renaming your repository to `todolistjquery` so it will be hosted at https://nezmustafa123.github.io/todolistjquery/.